# Data save into MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am getting the below exception while trying to save data into database using spring MVC and hibernate :

```
    [INFO] 2017-03-03 15:26:22,487 
stdout write - org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: 
Invalid property 'txnId' of bean class [com.entity.TxnCustomer]: Getter for property 'txnId' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Part of the Entity :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="TXN_ID")
private Integer txnId;


public TxnCustomer() {
}

public Integer getTxnId() {
    return this.txnId;
}

public void setTxnId(Integer txnId) {
    this.txnId = txnId;
}
```

I don't understand why I this exception occurs.

The mysql DB contains `txn_id` field which is set as auto increment.

Comment: Yes, txnId is integer

Comment: check once your mapping with the correct table

Answer (score 0):

use int instead of  Integer

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="TXN_ID")
private int txnId;

public TxnCustomer() {
}

public int getTxnId() {
  return this.txnId;
}

public void setTxnId(int txnId) {
  this.txnId = txnId;
}
```